# Is the expression "As it goes without saying" technically sound and formal?

Tags: meaning, formality

I am a non-native junior researcher, and in one of my academic reports, I want to write the following sentence to begin my paragraph.

> **As** *it* goes without saying, not all customers are the same.

**My questions:**

1. Is the word "**As**" at the beginning of the sentence redundant? Is
   it correct to keep "*it*"? How does the meaning change without "**As**/*it*"?
2. Is this sentence suitable for formal academic writing? If not,
   could you please provide me with some suitable suggestions with the
   same meaning?

Thank you for your time and attention in advance

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28As+goes+without+saying%29%2B%28as+goes+without+saying%29%2C%28As+it+goes+without+saying%29%2B%28as+it+goes+without+saying%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10&case_insensitive=true) showing that pronoun ***it*** isn't normally included with this particular "set phrase". If you don't include ***as*** at the beginning, you'd normally have relativiser ***that*** at the end (and no comma) instead: *It goes without saying **that** not all customers are the same* (I've no particular preference on that choice).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much for your help. This is absolutely useful.

Comment: Personally, I find ***it*** "obtrusively non-idiomatic" here, and I'm surprised to see how *often* it occurs in that linked chart above, even if it *is* a "minority" usage. The difference is much more extreme with closely-related expressions such as *As [it] is normal* or *As [it] is to be expected* - but to my mind, including ***it*** is always a bit "clumsy" in such constructions.

Comment: You could rephrase and take the focus away from the downside by incorporating the thought and building on it: *Because all customers are not the same, ...*

Comment: "As it happens" is one case where "it" is needed.

Comment: @StuartF: [***That's** as may be*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=That%27s+as+it+may+be%2CThat%27s+as+may+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThat%20%27s%20as%20may%20be%3B%2Cc0), but ***this*** is one more case where "it" is almost ***never*** included!

Comment: The idiomatic phrase would be: *It goes without saying that not all customers are the same.* However, if it goes without saying, then don't say it. (And this would not be suitable for formal academic writing.)

Comment: (Begin paragraphs with a hook.) Not all customers are the same, so it goes w/o saying that... (so that when I scan the page looking the 'customers' paragraph, it's the third word.)

Comment: "It goes without saying" is unfortunately familiar in the U.S., and it surprised me to hear that "as goes without saying" is idiomatic elsewhere. I would avoid it in all cases.

Comment: Here's a formal way you can express your idea: "clearly."  "Clearly, not all customers are the same."